# Is there a way to Find the Transportation mode in ios using core location

Tags: ios

I am writing an app which need to find the user transportation activity (like user is traveling in car or public transit or walking ). can any one please help me out .

Comment: Do you want the app to tell which mode of transportation user is using ?

Comment: yes exactly i am looking for mode of transportation user is using

Comment: This is not possible. You can get the route based on mode of transportation but you cant tell which mode of transport user is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did research on this I finally realized that Apple will not provide any mode of transportation instead it gives information  on Activity which are  stationary ,walking ,running ,automotive .
for complete reference 
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/core-motion-activity-tracking-in-ios-7/